# passing member tuple to non-member struct without specifying it in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

To avoid XY problem, I have a class with heterogeneous container, basically `std::tuple`. I want to make the class be able to accept Visitors, applying them to every element of tuple (not really sure if I'm applying it statically). Visitors' visit function will be templatized, so they will be able to fully use specializations of some types.

**Problem:**

When I want to apply Visitor I need to iterate over a container grabbing information about the Visitor, the tuple, and the index of element that is about to be visited. But when I wanted to create member function, I found that I can't partly specialize it. This is the solution I came up with, but I would like to somehow pass tuple without specifying containing types of tuple in template parameters.

```
#pragma once
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template <typename Visitor, int N, typename ... DataTypes>
struct Extractor
{
    static void applyVisitor(Visitor& v, std::tuple<DataTypes...>& t)
    {
        Extractor<Visitor, N - 1, DataTypes...>::applyVisitor(v, t);
        v.visit(std::get<N>(t));
    }
};

template <typename Visitor, typename ... DataTypes>
struct Extractor <Visitor, 0, DataTypes...>
{
    static void applyVisitor(Visitor& v, std::tuple<DataTypes...>& t)
    {
        v.visit(std::get<0>(t));
    }
};

template <typename ... DataTypes>
class MyTuple
{
    std::tuple<DataTypes...> data;
public:
    MyTuple(std::tuple<DataTypes...> data_) : data(data_) {}

    template <typename Visitor>
    void acceptVisitor(Visitor& v)
    {
        Extractor<Visitor, sizeof...(DataTypes) - 1, DataTypes...>::applyVisitor(v, data);
    }
};
```

I'm thinking in terms of OOD, so that every function that operate on data of the class should be preferably member function, but seems like C++ templates are from another world. If I'm not doing things right, please suggest another solution.

**EDIT:**

As asked asked in the comments, here is the example of visitor and the client calling `acceptVisitor()`

Visitor

```
#pragma once
#include <iosfwd>

class Visitor
{
    std::ostream& os;
public:
    Visitor(std::ostream& outputStream) :os(outputStream) {}

    template <typename T>
    void visit(T& data)
    {
        std::cout << data << "\n";
    } 
};
```

Main

```
#include "HeteContainer.h"
#include "Visitor.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    Visitor v(std::cout);
    MyTuple<int, int, std::string> m({ 1, 1, "abc" });
    m.acceptVisitor(v);

    std::system("pause");
}
```

Comment: It would help if you wrote a "test" of some sort that demonstrated how you wished the interface would work, even if it didn't compile.

Comment: @AndyG It is so bad that I'm aware of downvotes, but I have working example, will post it shortly.

Comment: You probably only want [simple expansion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae23af5d4df61114)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid recursion and use `std::index_sequence` instead:

```
template <typename Visitor, typename... DataTypes, std::size_t... Idx>
void applyVisitor(Visitor& v, std::tuple<DataTypes...>& t, std::index_sequence<Idx...>)
{
    using expander=int[];
    (void)expander{ (v.visit(std::get<Idx>(t)), 0)... };
}
```

Then your `acceptVisitor` function becomes this:

```
template <typename Visitor>
void acceptVisitor(Visitor& v)
{
    applyVisitor(v, data, std::index_sequence_for<DataTypes...>{});
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfa804a1df4e9944)

Comment: This seems like what I need, but @Piotr 's solution looks better and looks like it does the same thing. Is there runtime cost of casts or will they be optimized away?

Comment: They're pretty much the same. The casts are just to make it explicit that we're ignoring the result of the expression.